# Laptop computer grahpic opens and loads slowly

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, graphics

So i have this laptop whenever i open a folder, close a folder, or do anything graphical it runs slowly. and when i say slow i mean you can actually SEE in slowmo the animation running.

Say for instance you want to open a folder. you can see the full animation for about 2 - 3 seconds untill your folder is ready to use.

The odd thing is that all programs seem to be running on normal speed execpt for the graphics.

I have no idea what the problem could be and was hoping to get some answers out of you guys.

my specs are:

```
    ------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 7/14/2013, 21:13:19
       Machine name: NICOLAJ-PC
   Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.130318-1533)
           Language: Danish (Regional Setting: Danish)
System Manufacturer: CLEVO                            
       System Model: P15xEMx
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 03/09/12 14:47:56 Ver: 04.06.05
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.6GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8088MB RAM
          Page File: 2884MB used, 13290MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 120 DPI (125 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 3: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 4: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
       Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
          Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
           DAC type: Internal
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0166&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_09
     Display Memory: 1696 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 64 MB
      Shared Memory: 1632 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: unknown
         Monitor Id: LGD02D9
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (59.906Hz)
        Output Type: Internal
        Driver Name: igdumd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll,igdumd32,igd10umd32,igd10umd32
Driver File Version: 8.15.0010.2653 (English)
     Driver Version: 8.15.10.2653
        DDI Version: 11
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.1
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 2/14/2012 04:47:38, 8086528 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: n/a
    WHQL Date Stamp: n/a
  Device Identifier: {D7B78E66-4226-11CF-B57C-0F71A9C2C535}
          Vendor ID: 0x8086
          Device ID: 0x0166
          SubSys ID: 0x51051558
        Revision ID: 0x0009
 Driver Strong Name: oem258.inf:IntelGfx.NTamd64.6.0:iIVBM0:8.15.10.2653:pci\ven_8086&dev_0166
     Rank Of Driver: 00E62001
        Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C ModeWMV9_C ModeVC1_C 
   Deinterlace Caps: {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
       D3D9 Overlay: Supported
            DXVA-HD: Supported
       DDraw Status: Enabled
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Enabled

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_15585105&REV_1003
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.6526 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 12/13/2011 12:27:30, 4718952 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_15585105&REV_1003
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.6526 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 12/13/2011 12:27:30, 4718952 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: EuMusDesign_VAC_WDM
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: vrtaucbl.sys
         Driver Version: 4.10.0000.2964 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 7/9/2013 21:42:40, 66728 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: EuMus Design
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: EuMusDesign_VAC_WDM
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: vrtaucbl.sys
         Driver Version: 4.10.0000.2964 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 7/9/2013 21:42:40, 66728 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: EuMus Design
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

---------------------
Sound Capture Devices
---------------------
            Description: Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)
  Default Sound Capture: Yes
  Default Voice Capture: Yes
            Driver Name: vrtaucbl.sys
         Driver Version: 4.10.0000.2964 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 7/9/2013 21:42:40, 66728 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0x0

            Description: Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)
  Default Sound Capture: No
  Default Voice Capture: No
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.6526 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 12/13/2011 12:27:30, 4718952 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0x0

            Description: Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)
  Default Sound Capture: No
  Default Voice Capture: No
            Driver Name: vrtaucbl.sys
         Driver Version: 4.10.0000.2964 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 7/9/2013 21:42:40, 66728 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0x0

------------
PS/2 Devices
------------
+ Standard PS/2 Keyboard
| Matching Device ID: *pnp0303
| Service: i8042prt
| 
+ Terminal Server Keyboard Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_kbd
| Upper Filters: kbdclass
| Service: TermDD
| 
+ Synaptics PS/2 Port Pointing Device
| Matching Device ID: *pnp0f13
| Upper Filters: SynTP
| Service: i8042prt
| 
+ Microsoft USB IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0 (Mouse and Keyboard Center)
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x045E, 0x0047
| Matching Device ID: hid\vid_045e&pid_0047
| Upper Filters: Point64
| Service: mouhid
| 
+ Terminal Server Mouse Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_mou
| Upper Filters: mouclass
| Service: TermDD

--------------
System Devices
--------------
     Name: Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&A0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 - 1E10
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E10&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_C4\3&11583659&0&E0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Realtek PCIE CardReader
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_5289&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_01\4&26B74E12&0&00E1
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E2D
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E2D&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&D0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller - 1E03
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E03&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FA
   Driver: n/a

     Name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670M
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1213&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_A1\4&15491A0A&0&0008
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E26
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E26&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&E8
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0166&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Host Controller - 1E22
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E22&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FB
   Driver: n/a

     Name: 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller - 0154
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0154&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_09\3&11583659&0&00
   Driver: n/a

     Name: High Definition Audio Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E20&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&D8
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Xeon(R) processor E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port - 0151
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0151&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_09\3&11583659&0&08
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 - 1E16
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E16&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_C4\3&11583659&0&E3
   Driver: n/a

     Name: 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_197B&DEV_2380&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_30\4&7499319&0&00E3
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller - 1E57
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E57&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&F8
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 - 1E14
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E14&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_C4\3&11583659&0&E2
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8723&SUBSYS_072610EC&REV_00\4&16E0F379&0&00E2
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) Management Engine Interface 
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E3A&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_04\3&11583659&0&B0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 - 1E12
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E12&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_C4\3&11583659&0&E1
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_51051558&REV_0A\4&26B74E12&0&02E1
   Driver: n/a

------------------
DirectShow Filters
------------------

DirectShow Filters:
WMAudio Decoder DMO,0x00800800,1,1,WMADMOD.DLL,6.01.7601.17514
WMAPro over S/PDIF DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMADMOD.DLL,6.01.7601.17514
WMSpeech Decoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMSPDMOD.DLL,6.01.7601.17514
MP3 Decoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,mp3dmod.dll,6.01.7600.16385
Mpeg4s Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,mp4sdecd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
WMV Screen decoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvsdecd.dll,6.01.7601.17514
WMVideo Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,wmvdecod.dll,6.01.7601.18147
Mpeg43 Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,mp43decd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
Mpeg4 Decoder DMO,0x00800001,1,1,mpg4decd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
WMT VIH2 Fix,0x00200000,1,1,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
Record Queue,0x00200000,1,1,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
WMT Switch Filter,0x00200000,1,1,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
WMT Virtual Renderer,0x00200000,1,0,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
WMT DV Extract,0x00200000,1,1,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
WMT Virtual Source,0x00200000,0,1,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
WMT Sample Information Filter,0x00200000,1,1,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
DV Muxer,0x00400000,0,0,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Color Space Converter,0x00400001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
WM ASF Reader,0x00400000,0,0,qasf.dll,12.00.7601.17514
Screen Capture filter,0x00200000,0,1,wmpsrcwp.dll,12.00.7601.17514
AVI Splitter,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
VGA 16 Color Ditherer,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
SBE2MediaTypeProfile,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder,0x005fffff,2,4,msmpeg2vdec.dll,12.00.9200.16426
AC3 Parser Filter,0x00600000,1,1,mpg2splt.ax,6.06.7601.17528
StreamBufferSink,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
MJPEG Decompressor,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
DivX for Blizzard Decoder Filter,0x00800000,1,1,blizzard.ax,5.00.0002.0000
MPEG-I Stream Splitter,0x00600000,1,2,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
SAMI (CC) Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
VBI Codec,0x00600000,1,4,VBICodec.ax,6.06.7601.17514
MPEG-2 Splitter,0x005fffff,1,0,mpg2splt.ax,6.06.7601.17528
Closed Captions Analysis Filter,0x00200000,2,5,cca.dll,6.06.7601.17514
SBE2FileScan,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Microsoft MPEG-2 Video Encoder,0x00200000,1,1,msmpeg2enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
Internal Script Command Renderer,0x00800001,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MPEG Audio Decoder,0x03680001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
DV Splitter,0x00600000,1,2,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Video Mixing Renderer 9,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft MPEG-2 Encoder,0x00200000,2,1,msmpeg2enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
ACM Wrapper,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Video Renderer,0x00800001,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MPEG-2 Video Stream Analyzer,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Line 21 Decoder,0x00600000,1,1,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Video Port Manager,0x00600000,2,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Video Renderer,0x00400000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
File Writer,0x00200000,1,0,WLXVAFilt.dll,15.04.3538.0513
VPS Decoder,0x00200000,0,0,WSTPager.ax,6.06.7601.17514
WM ASF Writer,0x00400000,0,0,qasf.dll,12.00.7601.17514
VBI Surface Allocator,0x00600000,1,1,vbisurf.ax,6.01.7601.17514
File writer,0x00200000,1,0,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
iTV Data Sink,0x00600000,1,0,itvdata.dll,6.06.7601.17514
iTV Data Capture filter,0x00600000,1,1,itvdata.dll,6.06.7601.17514
DVD Navigator,0x00200000,0,3,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Overlay Mixer2,0x00200000,1,1,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17713
AVI Draw,0x00600064,9,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
RDP DShow Redirection Filter,0xffffffff,1,0,DShowRdpFilter.dll,
Microsoft MPEG-2 Audio Encoder,0x00200000,1,1,msmpeg2enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
WST Pager,0x00200000,1,1,WSTPager.ax,6.06.7601.17514
MPEG-2 Demultiplexer,0x00600000,1,1,mpg2splt.ax,6.06.7601.17528
DV Video Decoder,0x00800000,1,1,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
SampleGrabber,0x00200000,1,1,qedit.dll,6.06.7601.18175
Null Renderer,0x00200000,1,0,qedit.dll,6.06.7601.18175
MPEG-2 Sections and Tables,0x005fffff,1,0,Mpeg2Data.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft AC3 Encoder,0x00200000,1,1,msac3enc.dll,6.01.7601.17514
StreamBufferSource,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
Smart Tee,0x00200000,1,2,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Overlay Mixer,0x00200000,0,0,qdvd.dll,6.06.7601.17713
AVI Decompressor,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
AVI/WAV File Source,0x00400000,0,2,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Wave Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MIDI Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Multi-file Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
File stream renderer,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder,0x005fffff,1,1,msmpeg2adec.dll,6.01.7140.0000
StreamBufferSink2,0x00200000,0,0,sbe.dll,6.06.7601.17528
AVI Mux,0x00200000,1,0,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Line 21 Decoder 2,0x00600002,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
File Source (Async.),0x00400000,0,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
File Source (URL),0x00400000,0,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Infinite Pin Tee Filter,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Enhanced Video Renderer,0x00200000,1,0,evr.dll,6.01.7601.17514
BDA MPEG2 Transport Information Filter,0x00200000,2,0,psisrndr.ax,6.06.7601.17669
MPEG Video Decoder,0x40000001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713

WDM Streaming Tee/Splitter Devices:
Tee/Sink-to-Sink Converter,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

Video Compressors:
WMVideo8 Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvxencd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
WMVideo9 Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvencod.dll,6.01.7600.16385
MSScreen 9 encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,wmvsencd.dll,6.01.7600.16385
DV Video Encoder,0x00200000,0,0,qdv.dll,6.06.7601.17514
MJPEG Compressor,0x00200000,0,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Cinepak Codec by Radius,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Intel IYUV codec,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Intel IYUV codec,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft RLE,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft Video 1,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514

Audio Compressors:
WM Speech Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMSPDMOE.DLL,6.01.7600.16385
WMAudio Encoder DMO,0x00600800,1,1,WMADMOE.DLL,6.01.7600.16385
IMA ADPCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
PCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft ADPCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
GSM 6.10,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Messenger Audio Codec,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
CCITT A-Law,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
CCITT u-Law,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
MPEG Layer-3,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713

Audio Capture Sources:
Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable),0x00200000,0,0,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable),0x00200000,0,0,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514
Microphone (Realtek High Defini,0x00200000,0,0,qcap.dll,6.06.7601.17514

PBDA CP Filters:
PBDA DTFilter,0x00600000,1,1,CPFilters.dll,6.06.7601.17528
PBDA ETFilter,0x00200000,0,0,CPFilters.dll,6.06.7601.17528
PBDA PTFilter,0x00200000,0,0,CPFilters.dll,6.06.7601.17528

Midi Renderers:
Default MidiOut Device,0x00800000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713
Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.06.7601.17713

WDM Streaming Capture Devices:
Realtek HD Audio Line input,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
Realtek HD Audio Mic input,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
Realtek HD Audio Stereo input,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
Virtual Cable 1,0x00200000,2,2,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
Virtual Cable 2,0x00200000,2,2,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
BisonCam, NB Pro,0x00200000,1,2,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

WDM Streaming Rendering Devices:
Realtek HD Audio output,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
Realtek HDA SPDIF Out,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
Virtual Cable 1,0x00200000,2,2,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514
Virtual Cable 2,0x00200000,2,2,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

BDA Network Providers:
Microsoft ATSC Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft DVBC Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft DVBS Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft DVBT Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSDvbNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514
Microsoft Network Provider,0x00200000,0,1,MSNP.ax,6.06.7601.17514

Video Capture Sources:
BisonCam, NB Pro,0x00200000,1,2,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

Multi-Instance Capable VBI Codecs:
VBI Codec,0x00600000,1,4,VBICodec.ax,6.06.7601.17514

BDA Transport Information Renderers:
BDA MPEG2 Transport Information Filter,0x00600000,2,0,psisrndr.ax,6.06.7601.17669
MPEG-2 Sections and Tables,0x00600000,1,0,Mpeg2Data.ax,6.06.7601.17514

BDA CP/CA Filters:
Decrypt/Tag,0x00600000,1,1,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708
Encrypt/Tag,0x00200000,0,0,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708
PTFilter,0x00200000,0,0,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708
XDS Codec,0x00200000,0,0,EncDec.dll,6.06.7601.17708

WDM Streaming Communication Transforms:
Tee/Sink-to-Sink Converter,0x00200000,1,1,ksproxy.ax,6.01.7601.17514

---------------
EVR Power Information
---------------
Current Setting: {5C67A112-A4C9-483F-B4A7-1D473BECAFDC} (Quality) 
  Quality Flags: 2576
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow half deinterlace
    Allow scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 100
  Balanced Flags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 50
  PowerFlags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 0
```

Comment: Check for malware and try disabling aero

Answer (score -1):

Problem found:
"Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000"

Intel integrated graphics are nearly the slowest modern graphics device anywhere.  A $50 add-in card can beat it, not by a lot, but still beats it.

Comment: You may be able to increase speed by small amounts if you get newer drivers. Go to intel.com and support and use the automatic driver scan tool to make sure you drivers are up to date.

Comment: But this problem started not long ago and ive used it for 2 years now

Comment: @Marc Having you been doing system maintenance? Defragging hard drive, windows updates, and driver updates?

Comment: Ive tried driver updates and windows update

Comment: Update if i set it to 16bits it works better any but ONLY in windows (folder) idea what it might be?

Comment: Defrag is also important!  If that has not been run this month do it.

Comment: @Marc "16 bit" uses half the data so the task completes faster.  The more special effect the more work it has to do the slower it goes.

Comment: @cybernard Amazing, you thought that Intel graphics are slow? Then now is the point of such computers nowadays? And how about defrag? Seriously?

Comment: @Roberts  A fragmented hard drive slows down the whole system.  If the registry is seriously fragmented your PC will be slow.

Comment: @cybernard It can't be that slow, it would randomly lag, not do things in slow motion!

Comment: everything is done in slow motion. :S

Comment: You have plenty of CPU and memory. I would still attempt a defragmentation of the hard drive.  In the BIOS can you change the amount of memory dedicated(not shared) to the graphics card?  64MB is pretty low, if possible try 128mb.  Otherwise we are going to have to start running benchmarks on each component to see where the problem is.

Comment: my bios does not allow me to change anything other than where to boot

Comment: **UPDATE** if i change theme to something without high contrast windows is working but when i open any program that requires higher graphics it slows down to slow motion again

Comment: This answer is ludicrous. Intel HD 4000 graphics out-perform many entry-level discrete cards from a few years ago. Modern integrated graphics are more than adequate for standard usage, and would not be the cause of problems like animating opening and closing folders.

Comment: @Marc   http://www.futuremark.com/support/downloads#3dmark
Goto there and download,install, and run the free version.  Report the final score,graphics, and physics score.